# Warum ist „Geschmack“ männlich, obwohl das Wort mit „Ge-“ anfängt?

Tags: gender, prefix

Mit *Ge-* anfangende Wörter seien sächlich, so wurde mir mal gesagt, weil sie ein Kollektiv bedeuten würden. Zum Beispiel sind sächlich:

> Gelände (←Land)
>   Gewässer (←Wasser)
>   usw.

Warum sind dann *Geschmack* und *Geruch* männlich? Sind sie etwa nicht das Kollektiv, das Dinge, die man schmeckt bzw. riecht, darstellen?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120029/discussion-on-question-by-c-p-warum-ist-geschmack-mannlich-obwohl-das-wort-m).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier stehen wir wieder vor der alten Frage, ob sich die Sprache nach den Regeln richtet, oder ob die Regeln der Versuch sind, die Sprache zu beschreiben.

Tatsächlich ist es so, dass Menschen schon Sprache benutzt haben, als noch niemand auf die Idee kam, Regeln zu deren Gebrauch zu formulieren. Das ist übrigens auch der normale Weg des Spracherwerbs, den Kleinkinder beschreiten. Kinder hören zu und sprechen dann nach. Kinder sind nicht in der Lage, anzugeben nach welchen Regeln sie sich beim Sprechen richten, und auch Erwachsene benutzen Sprache fast immer, ohne an Regeln zu denken. Der Normalfall ist, dass man viele der Regeln gar nicht kennt. (Ich habe z.B. noch nie zuvor von der Regel mit den »Ge-«-Wörtern gehört.)

Regeln, die man in klugen Büchern findet, und die von Lehrern an Schüler weitergegeben werden, sind kein Korsett, in das sich die Sprache zu zwängen hat. Sie sind der nachträgliche Versuch, auffällige Muster in der Sprache zu beschreiben. Aber nicht alle Muster verlaufen in der natürlichen Sprache so schön sauber und geradlinig, wie es die einfachen Regeln oft vorgaukeln.

Gerade im Fall natürlicher Sprachen gibt es daher zu fast jeder Regel eine ganze Reihe von Ausnahmen, und die Nominalklassen von Substantiven in natürlichen Sprachen (die im Deutschen durch das grammatikalische Geschlecht und somit durch den Artikel wiedergegeben werden) sind ein hervorragendes Beispiel für das Versagen von Regeln.

Ganz offensichtlich ist das dort der Fall, wo einander widersprechende Regeln auf denselben Begriff anzuwenden sind.

Ein Beispiel:
Regel 1: Das grammatikalische Geschlecht weiblicher Personen ist weiblich.
Regel 2: Das grammatikalische Geschlecht von Verkleinerungsformen ist sächlich.

»Mädchen« ist eine weibliche Person und zugleich eine Verkleinerungsform (nämlich die Verkleinerung der Magd).

> Nach Regel 1: Dort drüben steht **eine** Mädchen, **sie** sieht sehr hübsch aus.
>   Nach Regel 2: Dort drüben steht **ein** Mädchen, **es** sieht sehr hübsch aus.

Im »wirklichen Leben« werden die beiden widersprechenden Regeln aber gerne vermischt:

> Tatsächlicher Gebrauch der Sprache: Dort drüben steht **ein** Mädchen, **sie** sieht sehr hübsch aus.

Comment: Es sieht sehr hübsch aus.

Comment: Das ist eine sehr allgemeine Antwort, die sich auf das Thema "Regeln in Sprachen" bezieht. Auf die konkrete Frage gibt das allerdings keine spezifische Antwort. Daher gebe ich hier -1. Die Antwort https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26608/15393 ist in meinen Augen deutlich besser, weil spezifischer.

Answer (score 10):

Ganz aus der Luft gegriffen ist die „Regel“ nicht, wonach Substantive mit der Vorsilbe *Ge-* Neutra seien. Es gibt nämlich gleich zwei Wortbildungsprozesse, die neutrale Substantive mit *Ge-* entstehen lassen; daneben gibt es aber auch andere Muster, die ebenfalls Substantive mit der Vorsilbe *Ge-*, aber nicht unbedingt neutralem Genus, produzieren und somit für die Ausnahmen von der Faustregel sorgen.

Zum einen wird *Ge-* genutzt, um Kollektivwörter aus anderen Substantiven abzuleiten; die sind dann Neutra: *Gehölz* (zu *Holz*), *Geflügel* (zu *Vogel* mit späterer Beeinflussung durch *Flügel*), *Gemüse* (zu *Mus*), *Geschmeide* (zu einem ausgestorbenen Wort *smîda* mit der Bedeutung ‘Metall’), *Gebein* (zu *Bein* in der Bedeutung ‘Knochen’), *Gerät* (zu *Rat* wie in *Hausrat*).

Zum zweiten dient *Ge-* auch der Bildung von abstrakten Begriffen aus Verben, die dann ebenfalls Neutra sind: *Geräusch* (zu *rauschen*), *Gestöber* (zu *stöbern*, *stieben*), *Gerüst* (zu *rüsten*), *Gebet* (zu *bitten*, *beten*).

Viele andere Substantive mit *Ge-* folgen völlig anderen Bildemustern, die gar nichts mit der Substantivvorsilbe *Ge-* zu tun haben. Beispielsweise kann aus einem Verb mit der Endung *-t*, ggf. mit Vokalwechsel, ein Substantiv abgeleitet werden (*die Fahrt* zu *fahren*); hat das Verb von vornherein schon ein *ge-*, bleibt dieses im Substantiv erhalten (*die Geburt* zu *gebären*). Von Verben auf *ge-* sind nach diesem Prinzip über verschiedene Bildeweisen etwa *die Geschichte* (zu *geschehen*) und *der Gehorsam* (zu *gehorchen*) abgeleitet.

Einige Verben hatten auch einmal die Vorsilbe *ge-* und sind danach ausgestorben oder haben die Vorsilbe verloren; die von ihnen damals abgeleiteten Substantive habe das *Ge-* behalten. Einige Beispiele hierfür sind *die Gewalt* (zu *gewalten*), *das Gewerbe* (zu *gewerben*) und auch *der Geschmack* (zu *geschmecken*), von dem die Frage ausging.

Schließlich gibt es natürlich auch noch Substantive, die zwar mit *Ge-* anfangen, bei denen das aber gar nicht diese Vorsilbe ist, wie etwa *die Gegend*, *das Genus*, *die Geranie* und *die Genese*.

Ein vergleichbarer Fall wäre die Faustregel, wonach Substantive auf *-e* häufig Feminina sind (*Lampe*, *Gabe*, *Biene* usw.). Auch sie hat eine gewisse sprachhistorische Grundlage (feminine ō-Stämme), aber auch reichlich Ausnahmen (*der Hase*, *das Auge* usw.).