# Genuskonflikt bei Relativpronomen

Tags: gender, relative-clause

### Hintergrund.

Ich versuche mit dieser Frage, ein interessantes Argument [in dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9581/1691) hervorzuheben und womöglich dessen Verallgemeinerung zu verstehen.

Ein Anteil solcher Antwort lautet:

> *Regel 1: Das grammatikalische Geschlecht weiblicher Personen ist weiblich.*
> *Regel 2: Das grammatikalische Geschlecht von Verkleinerungsformen ist sächlich.*
>
> […]
>
> *Nach Regel 1: Dort drüben steht eine Mädchen, sie sieht sehr hübsch aus.
>
> Nach Regel 2: Dort drüben steht ein Mädchen, es sieht sehr hübsch aus.*
>
> Tatsächlicher Gebrauch der Sprache: Dort drüben steht **ein** Mädchen, **sie** sieht sehr hübsch aus.

---

### Frage

Ich ahne *Mädchen* ist nicht das einzige Wort, für das solche nach Ausnahme klingende Konstruktion benutzt wird. Anscheinend findet man dieses grammatische Verhältnis auch bei etwa *jemand*:

Nehmen wir an, ein gewisser *Hans* lernt eine Frau aus dem Saarland kennen.

Soll er sagen

> Hans: „Ich habe jemanden kennengelernt, der aus dem Saarland kommt.“

damit der Relativsatz gut gebaut wird? Oder

> „Ich habe jemanden kennengelernt, die aus dem Saarland kommt.“

um anzudeuten, dass diese Person eine Frau ist. Das ist aber von dem, der auf diese Frage antwortet, noch zu bestätigen.

Die Frage lautet, für welche andere Wörter gibt's einen solchen Genuskonflikt?

Comment: Doch, Genus ist sächlich. Daher auch im Plural "Genera" (Neutra bekommen im Lateinischen ein a als Pluralendung).

Comment: Bonusfrage: Was passiert, wenn du nicht weißt, welches Geschlecht dieser jemand hat, aber annimmst, dass es eine Sie ist? ;) [Antwort ist zweifelslos, dass du diesen Fakt bei entsprechendem Satzbau ignorierst, dennoch neigt man gerne dazu, das Geschlecht betonen zu wollen, so dass keinerlei Missverständnisse entstehen können.]

Comment: Achja, die Antwort auf deine Frage, für welche Wörter es gilt, ist recht simple: Für ein jedes Wort, welches keine Aussage, über das Geschlecht trifft. "Mensch", "Person", "Individuum", "Kind", "Baby" – theoretisch auch "Leute" oder "man", hier läuft man aber imho nicht in das Problem, da es ja eine unspezifierte Menge an Personen ist, wo jede dieser Personen ein beliebiges Geschlecht annehmen kann.

Comment: ...zumal im Deutschen im Plural Geschlechter nicht unterschieden werden. Bei "Sie kommen" ist es völlig egal, ob sich die Gruppe aus "ers" oder "sies" zusammensetzt.

Comment: Ich fing schon an einen Kommentar zu schreiben, dass in der natürlichen Sprache hier eher "es" als "sie" verwendet wird - und beim darüber Nachdenken fiel mir auf dass ich wohl auch eher "sie" sagen würde. Ich denke dass es viel mit @Toscho's Syntax vs. Semantik zu tun hat. Wenn ein 5-jähriges Mädchen mitten auf der Straße steht, würde ich eher sagen "Schau mal das Mädchen, *es* wird gleich vom Auto überfahren" (die "Weiblichkeit" der Person ist hier irrelevant); bei einer 17-jährigen, die mir gut gefällt, tritt die "Weiblichkeit" in den Vordergrund, was dann zum "*sie* sieht gut aus" führt.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm das wäre eine abhängige Antwort wert!

Comment: @c.p. Nein, weil es ein anekdotischer Einzelfall ist, keine allgemeine Regel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es muss heißen

> Dort drüben steht ein Mädchen, das sehr hübsch aussieht.

und ebenso

> Ich habe jemanden kennengelernt, der aus dem Saarland kommt.

Gerade Letzteres mag einem widerstreben, wenn es sich um eine Frau handelt. In diesem Falle muss man halt umformulieren. Die Formulierung mit zwei Hauptsätzen macht

> Dort drüben steht ein Mädchen, sie sieht sehr hübsch aus.

gerade so akzeptabel, ich würde mir aber zumindest einen Punkt an Stelle des Kommas wünschen.

Übrigens gibt es das Phänomen auch in der anderen Richtung.

> Ihr Mann war die zweite Person aus dem Saarland, die ich kennen gelernt habe.

Comment: +1 für die tolle Konstruktion der `Mädchen`beispiele, bei denen man syntaktische und semantische Referenz erkennt.

Comment: Man sagt "jemand, der", doch gleichzeitig "jemand Nettes". Kannst du bitte etwas zu diesem Thema sagen?

Answer (score 6):

Vorneweg: `jemand` ist kein Relativprononem, sondern ein Indefinitpronomen. Substantivisch gebraucht ist es ein Maskulinum.

Ganz im Allgemeinen gibt es keinen „Genuskonflikt“. Ein Wort und dessen Bedeutung sind zwei völlig verschiedene Dinge. `Mädchen` ist ein gerne herangezogenes Beispiel:

- Das Wort `Mädchen` ist ein Neutrum (Genus). Syntaktische Referenzen, z. B. Relativpronomen (siehe Antwort von Carsten Schultz), spiegeln diese Tatsache immer wider.
- Ein Mädchen (d. h. die Bedeutung des Wortes `Mädchen`) ist ein junger, weiblicher (biologisches Geschlecht) Mensch. Semantische Referenzen spiegeln dieses biologisch weibliche Geschlecht durch das grammatikalische Genus Femininum wider.

Personalpronomen können syntaktische oder semantische Referenzen sein, je nachdem ob sie sich auf das Wort oder dessen Bedeutung beziehen. Deswegen kann man von einem Mädchen sagen:

> Es sieht gut aus. (Syntaktische Referenz)
>
> Sie sieht gut aus. (Semantische Referenz)