# Natürliches vs. grammatikalisches Geschlecht: wechselndes Pronomen?

Tags: gender, pronoun

Aus dem Deutschbuch<sup>1</sup> meines Sohnes:

> [… kurze Beschreibung des Unterschieds zwischen natürlichem und grammatikalischem Geschlecht anhand des Begriffs *Mädchen* …] Das kann zu Schwierigkeiten beim Gebrauch der Pronomen führen. Darum gilt die Regelung: **In dem Satz, in dem das Wort „Mädchen“ steht, benutzt man die sächliche Form des Pronomens („es“). Bei den nachfolgenden Pronomen benutzt man die weibliche Form („sie“).**

Weder mir noch meinem Mann (beide Muttersprachler) war eine derartige Regelung bekannt und vom Sprachgefühl her würden wir auch in längeren Texten konsequent das Pronomen passend zum *grammatikalischen* Geschlecht wählen – *Mädchen* bleibt *es*.

Frage:
Ist das einer der Fälle, in denen Sprachgefühl und Grammatikregeln kollidieren, oder steht in dem Buch einfach etwas Falsches bzw. Irreführendes?

Edit zur Klarstellung:
Das Schulbuch formuliert einen "Zwang" zum Genuswechsel, der weder meinem Sprachgefühl entspricht, noch in den diversen verlinkten Antworten gegeben scheint. Aus meiner Sicht (und auch laut den diversen Antworten) ist der Wechsel allenfalls *möglich*. - *Gibt es irgendeine Regel, wonach ein solcher Wechsel nicht nur erlaubt, sondern erzwungen wäre?*

---

<sup>1</sup> Deutschbuch 1, Sprach- und Lesebuch für Gymnasien in Baden-Württemberg; Cornelsen Verlag

Comment: Related: [Spricht man über ein Mädchen/eine Frau mittels “sie” oder “es”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2731/9551)

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11137/genuskonflikt-bei-relativpronomen

Comment: Ich beobachte, dass in den letzten Jahren auf das Wort »Mädchen« immer häufiger mit weiblichen Pronomen verwiesen wird. Einen Zwang zum Wechsel halte ich aber für regelwidrig. Zu vergleichen wäre das auch mit dem ebenfalls sächlichen *Weib*: »Dieses elende *Weib* ist echt fürchterlich. *Es/Sie* fängt mit jedem Streit an.«

Comment: Der durchgängige Gebrauch von Pronomen im Neutrum ist stark veraltet. Er kommt bspw. in Märchen wie „Das Mädchen mit den Schwefelhölzern“ vor. Darin hat das Kind allerdings auch keinen Namen und wird auch nie mit einem femininen Substantiv (z.B. _Tochter_ oder irgendwas auf _+in_) bezeichnet. Spätestens wenn verschiedene Substantive mit unterschiedlichem Genus (oder Namen) für dieselbe Person mit bekanntem Sexus verwendet werden, muss man Pronomen am natürlichen statt grammatischen Geschlecht ausrichten. Ansonsten besteht heute ohnehin die Tendenz dazu mit steigender Entfernung zum Substantiv.

Comment: Zum Nachtrag: Wer sollte eine feste Regel aufstellen können?

Comment: @chirlu Schulbücher stellen nicht nur im Sprachunterricht gerne Regelmäßigkeiten als Regeln dar. Auf dem Niveau kann das sogar zweckmäßig sein. PS: Die konsequente Ausrichtung am natürlichen Geschlecht ist natürlich seit jeher eine Forderung der feministischen Sprachkritik.

Comment: Das Thema wurde auch vor einigen Tagen nochmals von Dr.Bopp im canoo.net Blog aufgenommen. Vielleicht interessiert dich auch seine Stellungnahme. http://canoo.net/blog/2016/01/15/das-topmodel-uns-sein-freund/

Comment: Wer eine Form mit männlichem Protagonisten sucht: "Karl ist eine Respektsperson, der niemand zu widersprechen vermag, und (die/der) ... (ihre/seine) ... .

Comment: *Vong Sprachgefüh her*??? Bitte belege doch solche naiven Aussagen mit belastbaren Nachweisen. Cognitions-Wissenschaften tangieren auf diesem Brett nur am Rande. Mit weniger als einer belastbaren statistischen Erhebung kann ich so nicht arbeiten. *Das Schulbuch formuliert einen "Zwang"*? Es veranschaulicht das Problem selbst bei der Wahl der Pronomen auf der Metaebene: passivisch ohne Subjekt ("Das kann zu ... führen"), gefolgt von zweimal Indefinitpronomen ("benutzt man"). *Cornelsen*?! Praktikanten am Werk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein ähnlicher Gebrauch wird in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* beschrieben. Demnach ist beim Pronomen das Femininum wie das Neutrum möglich, wobei die feminine Form besonders dann bevorzugt wird, wenn das Pronomen weiter entfernt steht.

> Das Mädchen hat gestern **seine** (*seltener:* ihre) Puppe vergessen.
>
> Das Mädchen fand rasch Freundinnen. Besonders bemühte **sie** sich um **ihre** Tischnachbarin.

Dieser Gebrauch wird jedoch nicht wie in dem in der Frage zitierten Schulbuch als *Regelung* bezeichnet. (Lediglich die Verwendung von *seine* in „Das Mädchen hat gestern *seine* Puppe vergessen.“ ist als die von der Dudenredaktion empfohlene Variante gekennzeichnet.)

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe 50 Belege ausgewertet, in dem sich im selben Satz ein Pronomen auf ein vorangegangenes Mädchen bezieht. Es ist ein Verhältnis von 27 sie zu 23 es. 50 Belege sind nicht die Welt, aber ich erwarte da keine massiven Veränderungen.

Ich persönlich kann das völlig mit meinem Sprachgefühl vereinbaren. Das Mägdlein ist ja nur auf Grund des Diminutivs sächlich; der Sprecher weiß aber, dass es eigentlich weiblich ist. "Sie" ist daher semantisch angemessen.
In einem Fall gibt es sogar einen wilden Wechsel:

> Einige Zeit wohnte das Mädchen beim Vater, dann bei der Oma, mit der **sie** sich nicht verstand, dann kam **es** zu Pflegeeltern, dann zog **es** zur Mutter, die mittlerweile in Norwegen lebte, dann kam **sie** wieder zurück ins Elternhaus in den Kreis Altenkirchen.

Comment: Bei dem chaotischen Beispiel rollen sich mir die Zehennägel...

Comment: Schöner Fund, jup

Answer (score 1):

Vorneweg: Ich tendiere dazu, sobald ich auf *Mädchen* ein Pronomen folgen lasse, sofort *sie* statt *es* zu benutzen.

> Das Mädchen hat ihre Puppe verloren.

Steht dort *seine* muss ich kurz überlegen, ob es die Puppe des Mädchens ist, oder ob sie einem ungenannten Jungen gehört. Allein deswegen kann es eine Grammatikregel, die *es* notwendig verlangt, nicht geben.

Auch die Strenge, dass der Einfluss des Wortes *Mädchen* nur exakt bis zu einem Punkt reichen soll, wirkt auf mich an den Haaren herbeigezogen. Ich meine mich deutlich an ein Buch zu erinnern, in welchem durchgängig *es* geschrieben wurde, wenn ein Mädchen gemeint war. (Mein Gehirn verrät mir aber nicht, worum es sich gehandelt hat – spontan eher etwas Klassisches.)

Grammatikalisch ist eine solche Regel also Humbug. Dennoch kann sie ihre Berechtigung haben: Als Stilkunde. Womöglich sind die Macher des Schulbuchs der Meinung, dass nur stilistisch schön ist, was sich an diese Regel hält. Nun, das können sie halten wie sie wollen, Loong hat die ganz leicht abweichende Meinung der Duden-Redaktion zitiert. Man könnte aber genau so gut die beiden anderen Stilregeln aufstellen:

- > Immer, wenn das Pronomen das Wort *Mädchen* ersetzt, ist *es* zu schreiben.
- > Egal, ob das Wort *Mädchen* da steht, wenn das Pronomen sich auf eines bezieht, ist *sie* zu schreiben.

Beide Stilregeln haben unter den Schreibern hier Verfechter, man sollte keine zur allein selig machenden Wahrheit erheben.

Comment: Und wenn da 'ihre' steht, wieso musst Du nicht kurz überlegen, ob die Puppe einer ungenannten, anderen Weibsperson gehört? Oder musst Du das auch?

Comment: Allein weil Du es anders handhabst, kann es eine solche Regel nicht geben? Dem Rest stimme ich zu.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hab überlegen, warum ich nicht hab überlegen müssen, aber letztendlich ist es für mein Sprachzentrum der gleiche Satzbau wie »der Junge hat seinen Fußball verloren« – ich *erwarte,* dass da das entsprechende Pronomen steht, also nehme ich sofort an, dass die beiden zusammengehören. Analog zu »die Frau hat ihre Handtasche verloren« und »der Mann hat seine Brille verloren.« (Übrigens sind alle Sätze tendenziell sexistisch, aber das ist Selbstkritik.

Comment: @CarstenS Weil die Grammatik von zwei Personen verschieden gehandhabt wird, kann es keine **Grammatik**regel geben. Analog zur inexistenten Grammatikregel, dass *stehen* das Perfekt mit *sein* bildet.