# Which possessive pronoun should follow 'Kind' (female) or 'Mädchen' - feminine or neuter? Das Mädchen hat ihren (oder seinen) Hut verloren?

Tags: possessive-pronoun, possessive

Older texts would use the appropriate grammatical gender for possessive pronouns, eg,

> 'Das Weib hat seinen Hut verloren.'

Is this still the best usage, or should we now use the natural gender, ie,

> 'Das Weib hat ihren Hut verloren'

Comment: Still the same, and we have had questions about that. One very recently.

Comment: I only find questions in German. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27770/nat%c3%bcrliches-vs-grammatikalisches-geschlecht-wechselndes-pronomen

Comment: You wouldn't use *Weib* in contemporary Standard German. It's derogatory.

Comment: There is some nuance in this, so assuming that so far we really have discussed this only in German it would be nice if someone wrote an answer in English. My comment was not intended to discourage this.

Comment: Related (German) [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/59145/1696) targeting articles.

Comment: *seinen* shouldn't even be odd here, as it's geneticly related to *sie*.

Comment: Is the appropriate grammatical gender still best usage or should we ... that's clearly opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

You'd still say

> Das Weib hat seinen Hut verloren

although it's very uncommon today to refer to a women with "Das Weib". You would use "Die Frau" instead.

For "Mädchen",

> Das Mädchen hat seinen Hut verloren

would be grammatically correct, although you'll frequently hear

> Das Mädchen hat ihren Hut verloren

in colloquial language.

Comment: An example from 19th century literary language (Th. Storm): *Da zog das Mädchen **ihr** rotes Händchen aus dem Muff, und ihn zu sich ziehend, wies sie mit dem Finger nach dem Vogelbauer.*