# Warum ist das Genus von „Abschwung“ maskulin, obwohl Wörter auf „-ung“ meistens feminin sind?

Tags: gender

Der häufigste Artikel für Wörter mit der Endung *-ung* ist *die*. Warum ist das bei *Abschwung* anders? Warum sagen wir *der Abschwung* und nicht *die Abschwung*? Gibt es weitere Ausnahmen?

Comment: Erwartungsgemäß: Aufschwung.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Die »Ausnahme« ist bei genauer Betrachtung gar keine Ausnahme. Die Regel, dass die Endung *-ung* automatisch das weibliche Geschlecht verlangt, gilt nämlich nur für das Suffix *-ung*, das aus Verben Substantive macht. Es gibt allerdings auch Wörter, deren Stamm auf *-ung* endet, und die deswegen von dieser Suffixregel nicht betroffen sind.

Man kann die Wörter, die ein Suffix-*ung* haben, daran erkennen, dass es ein entsprechendes Verb gibt:

- *Entsteh**ung** ← entsteh**en***
- *Mess**ung** ← mess**en***
- *Erwart**ung** ← erwart**en***

Im Fall *Schwung* ist das dazugehörige Verb allerdings *schwingen* – und es existiert die Zusatzform *Schwing**ung***, die tatsächlich feminin ist.

Außerdem gibt es noch andere Wörter, die auf *-ung* enden, sich aber von keinem Verb direkt ableiten lassen, zum Beispiel *der Dung* (etwas entfernter von *düngen*; vgl. *Düngung*).

Eine Liste der »Ausnahmen« aufzustellen sollte jemand übernehmen, der ein entsprechendes Wörterbuch mit einem Skript auswerten kann.

Comment: Es gibt kaum Substantive auf *-ung*, bei denen es nicht das Wortbildungssuffix ist; außer _Schwung_ und _Dung_ nur noch _Sprung_, mit ihren jeweiligen Komposita (_Vorsprung_, _Rinderdung_ usw.). Ich hatte es mir angesehen als ein mögliches Beispiel für http://german.stackexchange.com/a/26608, fand es dann aber zu offensichtlich (für Muttersprachler) und habe *-e* genommen.

Comment: @chirlu Wenn man wöllte, könnte man noch Wörter hinzuzählen, bei denen das Schwa-_e_ am Ende manchmal ausfällt, aber mehr als _Jung(e)_ gibt es dann auch nicht zusätzlich, da _Zunge_ und _Lunge_ ohnehin feminin sind.

Comment: @chirlu das erklärt, warum mir ums verrecken keine eingefallen sind ;)

Comment: Der Harung ist wohl auch eine Ausnahme.

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler Ich kenne keinen Harung. Weder Wiktionary noch Duden.de noch DWDS.de kennen einen Harung. Was ist ein Harung?

Comment: Ein altes deutsches Wort für Hering

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler Das [etymologische Wörterbuch von Wolfgang Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hering#1) (direkt unter *Bedeutungen* bei *Etymologie*) listet viele verwandte Wörter von *Hering*, die alle auf *-ing* o.ä. enden. *Haring* ist dabei, *Harung* nicht. Da sich keine *-ung*-Form in den alten Formen findet, würde ich vermuten, dass hier irgendein Lautwandel aus dem /i/ zeitweise ein /u/ gemacht hat. Aber ja, dann wohl auch eine solche Ausnahme, bei der der Stamm aus zufällig auf *-ung* endet, da offensichtlich kein Suffix vorliegt.

Comment: Sorry, ich hätte eine Quelle angeben sollen... Auf der Seite http://faql.de/rechtschreibung.html#hering steht, dass es bei Grimm (1872) stehen würde...das habe ich aber nicht überprüft.

Comment: @Jan, in einen Harung, jung und stramm, zwo, drei, vier, ...

Answer (score 5):

[Der Hornung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hornung) (Altes Wort für Februar) ist aber wahrscheinlich ein Name und deshalb von der Regel ausgenommen.

Comment: Hi Falk Döring! Habe deiner Antwort einen Link zum DWDS hinzugefügt. Ich hoffe, das ist in deinem Sinne.