# Das Geschlecht der Wörter, die mit "Ge-" beginnen

Tags: noun, gender, morphology

Ich sehe, dass die meisten Wörter, die mit `**Ge**' beginnen, neutral sind, aber es gibt einige von ihnen wie **Gefahr**, die weiblich sind.

- Gibt es eine Regel oder ist es eine Ausnahme?

Comment: siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9572/43666

Comment: ... insbesondere die Antwort https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26608/43666

Comment: Der Gehalt der Frage wird von meinem Gevatter mit larmoyantem Gestus bestritten. :)